# Retrieving screenshot pic from service via controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, screenshot

I want to take screenshot with cordova-screenshot-plugin. Can i save that picture as variable or something so i can manipulate with it later? Service for taking screenshot :

```
.service('$cordovaScreenshot', ['$q', function($q) {

    return {
        capture: function(filename, extension, quality) {
            extension = extension || 'jpg';
            quality = quality || '100';

            var defer = $q.defer();
            console.log(defer);
            navigator.screenshot.save(function(error, res) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    defer.reject(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('screenshot saved in: ', res.filePath);
                    defer.resolve(res.filePath);
                }
            }, extension, quality, filename);

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I will try to take screenshot with button, and show it with popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cordova-Plugin-Screenshot](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot) API gives you the file path of the picture. This filepath is accessible from anywhere in the smartphone. So you could use the sample service given in the official github repository with something like that in your controller:

```
// app is define elsewhere in your application

app.controller('Awesome.Controller', AwesomeController);

AwesomeController.$inject = ['$cordovaScreenshot'];

function AwesomeController($cordovaScreenshot) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.onClick = takeScreenshot;

  function takeScreenshot() {
    $cordovaScreeshot.capture('mypic', 'jpg', 80).then(function(filepath) {
      vm.filepath = filepath;
    }
  }
}
```

With an HTML template like this:

```
<button on-click="vm.onClick()">take screenshot</button>

<div ng-if="vm.filepath">
  <p>Result: {{vm.filepath}}</p>
  <img ng-src="{{vm.filepath}}>
</div>
```